# Can a mobius strip manifold exist in $3$ dimensions?

Tags: general-topology

### Background and Question

I've always thought one can embed a manifold of dimensions $n$ into a higher dimension manifold of $R^{(n+1)}$. Is this true? If yes, what about the counter example below? If not, what is the minimum number of dimensions required?

### Counter example

The Mobius band is formed as a quotient of $X = [0, 1] \times R$. A point $(0,y)$ is identified with the point $(1,-y)$. Thus:

$$Y = [ (x,y) , [(x,y),(1,-y)| x \in (0,1),y \in R]$$

Now we shall try to embed this in dimensions $R^3$. Imagine doing this first with a finite width mobius strip and then take width to infinity later.  However, this cannot be done when the mobius strip has infinite length. Due to the twist in $3$ dimensional space will have infinite width when extending and hence, it is guaranteed to self intersect and will not be a manifold anymore! (try visualizing it, I wasn't sure how to draw this)

Comment: Note the [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem), which allows you to embed (under certain assumptions) in *twice* the dimension.

Answer (score 5):

When we talk about whether manifold $M$ can be embedded into $\Bbb{R}^N$ for some $N$, we mean whether a homeomorphic (or diffeomorphic) copy of $M$ can be embedded into $\Bbb{R}^N$, rather than a specific parameterization of $M$. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the open interval $(0,1)$, your construction of the open Mobius band as a quotient of $[0,1]\times \Bbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the analogous construction of the open Mobius band as a quotient of $[0,1]\times (0,1)$.

The open Mobius band $M$ is embeddable into $\Bbb{R}^3$. One can see this by the standard cut and paste construction with a sheet of paper. Take a finite length sheet of paper, twist one time, and glue one end to the other. Voila, you have a Mobius band in $\Bbb{R}^3$, that looks something like this:

[image]

Examples of surface that cannot be embedded into $\Bbb{R}^3$ include the [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) and the [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle).

As mentioned in the comments, the [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) says that any smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ can be smoothly embedded into $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: Two specific questions asked are answered in this post, but it may not be obvious. So to clarify: "is it true that an $n$-dimensional manifold can always be embedded in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$?" - No, the klein bottle and projective plane are counter-examples. "What about the counter-example below?" - that is not a valid counter-example, as it requires the embedding to satisfy an additional condition beyond simply being diffeomorphic to its image.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What is the name of that last condition?

Comment: @Crypton - not everything in mathmatics has a name attached to it. I was referring to the OP's using infinite width on the band to arrive at a contradiction. There is nothing in the definition of an embedding that requires the width of the Möbius strip be infinite.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see, thank you. I was wondering just in case.